# How to get the previous tag in liquibase?

Tags: azure-pipelines, liquibase, rollback, liquibase-maven-plugin

I am running gradle commands for liquibase to get the tag,validate,update.

I want to create a rollback as well. In my pipeline, how can get the last tag to rollback to ?
Where can I get the tags from.

```
  ./gradlew -Ddb_url=$DB_HOST_URL -Ddb_username= -Ddb_password=$DB_PASSWORD updateSQL -PrunList=main
  ./gradlew -Ddb_url=$DB_HOST_URL -Ddb_username= -Ddb_password=$DB_PASSWORD validate -PrunList=main
  ./gradlew -Ddb_url=
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to generate the SQL needed to rollback to the current state?

If so, you can use the `generateFutureRollbackSql` call to output that.

Otherwise, I don't know of a command that just returns the last tag. You could use a database query to get the last value of `tag` from the `databasechangelog` table via a database query plugin.